# Custom layout is not recognised as a <Route> component

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm trying to use custom routes in my React project, but I keep receiving the warning:

> `Error: [NoNavbarLayoutRoute] is not a <Route> component. All component children of <Routes> must be a <Route> or <React.Fragment>`

These are my 2 different layouts:

```
const NoNavbarLayoutRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
    return (
        <Route {...rest} render={matchProps => (
                <NoNavbarLayout>
                    <Component {...matchProps} />
                </NoNavbarLayout>
            )}
        />
    );
};

const NavbarLayoutRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
    return (
        <Route {...rest} render={matchProps => (
            <NavbarLayout>
                <Component {...matchProps} />
            </NavbarLayout>
        )}
        />
    );
};
```

This is an example what is in one of the layouts:

```
import React from "react";

const NoNavbarLayout = ({ children }) => (
    <div className="login-layout">
        <p>No navbar</p>
        {children}
    </div>
);

export default NoNavbarLayout;
```

And here is where I use them:

```
class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <BrowserRouter>
                    <Routes>
                        <NoNavbarLayoutRoute path="/bossHome" element={<BossHomePage />} />
                        <NavbarLayoutRoute path="/home" element={<Home />} />
                    </Routes>
                </BrowserRouter>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

From my understanding these layouts should be Route components, but there must be something I'm doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `react-router-dom` v6 there is no longer a use case/allowance for custom route components. Only `Route` (*or `Fragment`*) components can be children of the `Routes` component. The layout components are rendered on a `Route` component's `element` prop and they can render children components or `Outlets` if they are wrapping nested `Route` components.

Given a layout components rendering a `children` prop *:

```
const NoNavbarLayout = ({ children }) => (
  <div className="login-layout">
    <p>No navbar</p>
    {children}
  </div>
);
```

* I am assuming the `NavbarLayout` component is similar

The routes would look as such:

```
<Routes>
  <Route
    path="/bossHome"
    element={(
      <NoNavbarLayout>
        <BossHomePage />
      </NoNavbarLayout>
    )}
  />
  <Route
    path="/home"
    element={(
      <NavbarLayout>
        <Home />
      </NavbarLayout>
    )}
  />
</Routes>
```